# What is the equivalent of ruby's string inspect() in python

Tags: python, ruby, string

I apologize up front for the dumbness of this question, but I can't figure it out and its driving me crazy.

In ruby I can do:

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "\t\t\n"  
=> "\t\t\n"  
irb(main):003:0> puts s  

=> nil  
irb(main):004:0> puts s.inspect  
"\t\t\n"
```

Is there an equivalent of ruby's `inspect` function in python?

Answer (score 12):

[`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr):

```
>>> print repr('\t\t\n')
'\t\t\n'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use repr or  (backticks), I am doing the exactly the same things as you did above.

```
>>> s = "\t\t\n"
>>> s
'\t\t\n'
>>> print s


>>> repr(s)
"'\\t\\t\\n'"
>>> print repr(s)
'\t\t\n'
>>> print `s`
'\t\t\n'
```

Comment: Note that the backticks are deprecated: they were removed in Python 3.